# Naming values conditionally in R

Tags: r

Quick question here regarding assigning names to values in a vector conditionally. I have a simple vector in R with nine values (average temperature) that I am looking to assign a character vector to based on whether a value is greater than or less than 65. If the value is less than 65, I would like to assign HDD to the value as a row name (or column name) and if the value is greater than 65, I would like to assign CDD to the value.

```
x <- c(44.3, 49.3, 52.5, 46.2, 35.19, 67.4, 79.4, 13.4, 54.3)
```

Here's what I've been attempting along with some variations of this code as well, but I haven't gotten anywhere. I've also attempted a few loops, but those are not my strong point (new coder).

```
 x.rownames <- ifelse(x<65,(row.names(x) = "HDD"),(row.names(x) = "CDD"))
```

I keep getting the error :

```
Error in `rownames<-`(x, value) : 
  attempt to set 'rownames' on an object with no dimensions
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: `?row.names`: All data frames have a row names attribute, a character vector of length the number of rows with no duplicates nor missing values. Your `x `is not a df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just getting a bit confused with your R syntax

```
names(x) <- ifelse(x<65,(names(x) = "HDD"),(names(x) = "CDD"))
```

X is a vector, not a DF, so it doesn't have row names. R does support named vectors, so you can set the names as names(x)

Comment: `names(x) <- ifelse(x<65,"HDD","CDD")` would probably be better since calling `names()` in the `ifelse` really isn't appropriate.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. Yeah, it looks like I was over thinking it and adding the row.names in there instead of names. I appreciate the help very much from both of you.